# Download pages as PDF In MVC3 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, pdf-generation

I have a MVC3, Razor engine application having 8 different views(.cshtml).I have these pages for users to enter personal details and other things.I have a requirement to download the content of all these 8 pages(.cshtml) as shown in browser in a button click as a single PDF file and save it.The pages(.cshtml) contains controls like dropdownbox,calender,radio button etc.Some of the contents in the views are loaded from models.

Comment: A possibly helpful read: [Rendering ASP.NET content as PDF](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/02/04/rendering-asp-net-content-as-pdf/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [synchronised pechkin](https://github.com/gmanny/Pechkin) which is available as a [nuget package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Pechkin.Synchronized/0.5.8.1).

This works on html so you can use a templating engine like [RazorGenerator](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/06/precompile-your-mvc-views-using.html) to convert Razor views to html.